# Validate Call log

Tags: android

I am new to android. Can we delete call log entries by program. in which event we write the code for to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Using the content provider inteface you can use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.html) content provder to delete call logs.